# Laravel date changing when I update a variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I'm writing a scope query and I'm passing in a `fetch_date` to pull things from the DB table based on the `created_at` timestamp.

I'm trying to find all records for a month, but the variable `$fetch_date` keeps changing whenever I try the following:

```
    //$fetch_date is a carbon instance and is equal to the month the user selected 
    //ie: Carbon {#221 ▼
    //    +"date": "2016-07-01 00:00:00.000000"

    //Create the next_month
    $next_month = $fetch_date->addMonth();
    //Format next_month as a string
    $next_month = $next_month->format('Y-m-d');
    //Format fetch_date as a string
    $fetch_date = $fetch_date->format('Y-m-d');

    dd($fetch_date);
    //This now gives me 2016-08-01 - why?
```

Why does the `fetch_date` change? I'm essentially trying to keep the `$fetch_date` as the current month and the `$next_month` to simply be the start of the next month.

I'm guessing there's a real simple reason to this I'm just overlooking.

Comment: I think you are adding a month to the fetch_date variable. Try to copy it and then add the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because calling the `addMonth` method has side effects.

If you look at Carbon's [source](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/src/Carbon/Carbon.php#L2009), you'll see that all `addMonth` is doing is calling `addMonths` with a value of 1, which in turn is simply calling [`DateTime::modify`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php).  It's not explicitly spelled out in the documentation, but from the examples it's pretty plain that calling the method modifies the stored time value:

> Example #1 DateTime::modify() example

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2006-12-12');
$date->modify('+1 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

To avoid this, keep a copy of of the time around and modify that:

```
$also_fetch_date = clone $fetch_date;
$next_month = $also_fetch_date->addMonth();
// ...
```

Comment: Interesting - and explains exactly what was going on. Thank you for the thorough explanation; now I understand and your correction worked to solve the problem.

Comment: Uh, why add month/clone objects, when you could have simply used php's strtotime to achieve the desired effect. On the hand as well, it could also be done in one line using `->copy` method in Carbon.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are adding a month to the fetch_date variable.

Try this:

```
$next_month = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $fetch_date->format('Y-m-d'));
$next_month->addMonth();

dd($next_month->format('Y-m-d'));
```

Take a look at the documentation of Carbon: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/
Maybe will help you

Comment: Alright, I tried that. For some *crazy* reason, even after changing it to what you have done here - $fetch_date still gets changed.

I'm wondering if maybe my browser isn't caching something strange - because I have no idea how it's possible...

Comment: Try the new solution, to create a new carbon object named next_month